# Refactoring duplicate validation by array column wise

Tags: javascript

I am creating a functions to validate the array's duplicate by column wise from the given array. it works.  Any one help me to minimize my code:

```
const array = [
  [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8],
  [9,8,7,6,5,4,3,2]
];

const colLength = Array.from({length:8});
const rowFinder = [];
colLength.forEach((item,i) => {
  rowFinder[i] = rowFinder[i]||[]; 
  array.forEach((item, index) => {
    rowFinder[i].push(item[i]);
  })
});
let duplicate = false;
rowFinder.forEach((sub,i) => {
  const originanl = sub;
  const reduced = [...new Set(sub)];
  if(originanl.length !== reduced.length){
    duplicate =  true;
  }
});

console.log(duplicate); //true [5,5] fifth column identified as duplicate
```

Answer (score 2):

You have two `forEach` that define `item`, renaming one (the first to something like `num`) to something different will help clarify scope. As `rowFinder` doesn't seem to need to keep track of numbers, just if there is a duplicate, you can make it a list of type `Set`. Then you can check if it `has(item[i])` for duplicate check in the second `forEach` and remove the last loop.

```js
const array = [
  [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8],
  [9, 8, 7, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2]
];

let duplicate = false;
const colLength = Array.from({
  length: 8
});
const rowFinder = [];
colLength.forEach((num, i) => {
  rowFinder[i] = new Set();
  array.forEach((item, index) => {
    if(rowFinder[i].has(item[i])) {
      duplicate = true;
    }
    rowFinder[i].add(item[i]);
  })
});

console.log(duplicate); //true [5,5] fifth column identified as duplicate
```